# AWS root user is not authorized to perform: eks:DescribeCluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I am following this video guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcnviAwmzM4&t=1092s
According to the guide, I configured my aws-cli tool with the Secret Access Key ID and Secret Access Key of my root user. Anyway, when I issue the command

```
aws eks --region us-east-2 describe-cluster --name k8s-book --query cluster.status
```

I am getting the following error:

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the DescribeCluster operation: User: arn:aws:iam::896622344185:user/publishing-service-dev is not authorized to perform: eks:DescribeCluster on resource: arn:aws:eks:us-east-2:896622344185:cluster/k8s-book

My understanding is that the root user must have unrestricted access. Also, I don't get why in the command output instead of "root" user "user/publishing-service-dev" is mentioned. I don't have such as IAM user created. Actually, I do not have any IAM users.

Comment: `I configured my aws-cli tool with the Secret Access Key ID and Secret Access Key of my root user` - no, you didn't. You configured it with an IAM user called `publishing-service-dev`, which doesn't have the required permission.

Comment: How is that even possible? I used the same Secret Access Key ID and Secret Access Key in a virualbox machine and it works as expected. So the secrets are correct.

Answer (score 2):

You are not configuring the credentials of your root user, you're using credentials for `publishing-service-dev` IAM user

Check which IAM policies have that user attached (or which groups that user belongs to and their policies)

As best practices, [try not to use the root user at all](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#lock-away-credentials)

Comment: I don't have such IAM user. Also,  the same Secret Access Key ID and Secret Access Key in a virualbox machine and it works as expected. So the secrets are correct. So there is probably misconfiguration on my local machine but I don't know what exactly.

Comment: I got iit. There are environment variables overriding my shared credentials file. Now I just have to find where are they set.

Comment: You can check the env variables used for the AWS cli in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html. Check special attention to `$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` & `$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` that may be overriding your profile set by `$AWS_PROFILE`

Comment: But yes, you do have such IAM user in the account with ID `896622344185` as per the error says